# pass Socket , ObjectInputStream , ObjectOutputStream between Activites

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities in my client/server project:
1 - login (openning connection)
2 - Handeling the game.

i tired passing Socket , ObjectInputStream , ObjectOutputStream objects with Intenet and   startActivity but it can pass only serializable objects.
how can i pass this objects ?
i read that i can use the application tag for this use but i didn't understand how.
can you guys lead me to the solution
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you could do is store a reference to stream/socket objects in a statically accessible class, and then pick them up from the other activity.

Mandatory warning about static access in android: make sure that anything you store statically has **no** direct or indirect references to View or Activity objects, because this can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot serialize file objects (including sockets) as it would not make any sense this way.

But why do you need to pass the connection to the second activity anyway? Why not just do the following:

1. Login in the first activity, fetch some data you need about the user.
2. Pass the fetched data to the second activity. If you need to communicate with the server, just open a new connection in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to start a service you can create a global variable.

Create a Singleton pattern for that socket like this:

```
public class SocketSingleton {


private static Socket socket;

public static void setSocket(Socket socketpass){
    SocketSingleton.socket=socketpass;
}

public static Socket getSocket(){
    return SocketSingleton.socket;
    //return socket;
}
```

}

Then in the code just change the global value:

```
        public void changeScreen(Socket socket, String ip, int port) {
        SocketSingleton.setSocket(socket);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ControlActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("ip", ip);
        i.putExtra("port",port);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```