# How to pass socket value between intent

Tags: android

I have an application which is having login page ie my 1st intent and i hav a 2nd intent which is having some button and edittext but as soon as my app goes to second intent the 1st intent will end closing the connection between client and the server.pls help me to find how not to end the connection b/w client and server.

Comment: Your passing data from one Intent to another? You need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: Ya i checked the link u specified but when i send objects using Serialisible my application closes unexpectedly and it says the class can not implement serialiasible.how to fix that problem.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277876/pass-socket-objectinputstream-objectoutputstream-between-activites

Comment: can the static member or static class in one intent can be referenced from other intent.

Comment: I am not sure, I have only passed strings from one activity to another. I thought I could help out with a link :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want a `Service` to manage the connection. A `Service` normally has a longer lifetime than that of an individual `Activity`.

You can have each `Activity` bind to the `Service` when created, and disconnect from the `Service` on exit.